# Dagger 2 Factory Class Injection

Tags: android, dagger-2, factory-pattern

I have a `DataSource` interface and two concrete classes which implemets this interface (local, remote). And i will use this classes in `Repository` class with constructor injection.

I wonder if its good idea to create a `DataSourceFactory` class then inject concrete `local` and `remote` classes into this `factory` class and then inject this factory class into `Repository` class. With this way there is no need to create module for binding interfaces and easier to manege in more complex cases.

Hope i am clear enough. Thanks.

Edit: provide code.

```
    public interface DataSource {
        String getMovieName();
    }


    public class LocalDataSource implements DataSource {

        @Inject
        public LocalDataSource() {
        }

        @Override
        public String getMovieName() {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public class RemoteDataSource implements DataSource {

        @Inject
        public RemoteDataSource() {
        }

        @Override
        public String getMovieName() {
            return "";
        }
    }

    // Without factory.

    @Module
    public abstract class DataSourceModule {

        @Binds
        @Local
        abstract DataSource bindLocalDataSource(LocalDataSource localDataSource);

        @Binds
        @Remote
        abstract DataSource bindRemoteDataSource(RemoteDataSource remoteDataSource);
    }

    public class Repository implements DataSource {

        private final DataSource localDataSource;
        private final DataSource remoteDataSource;

        @Inject
        public Repository(@Local DataSource localDataSource, @Remote DataSource remoteDataSource) {
            this.localDataSource = localDataSource;
            this.remoteDataSource = remoteDataSource;
        }

        @Override
        public String getMovieName() {
            String name = localDataSource.getMovieName();
            return name.isEmpty() ? remoteDataSource.getMovieName() : name;
        }

    }

    //With data source factory

    public class DataSourceFactory{

        private final LocalDataSource localDataSource;
        private final RemoteDataSource remoteDataSource;

        @Inject
        public DataSourceFactory(LocalDataSource localDataSource, RemoteDataSource remoteDataSource) {
            this.localDataSource = localDataSource;
            this.remoteDataSource = remoteDataSource;
        }

        public static DataSource createLocalDataSource(){
            return localDataSource;
        }

        public static DataSource createRemoteDataSource(){
            return remoteDataSource;
        }

    }

    public class Repository implements DataSource {

        private final DataSource localDataSource;
        private final DataSource remoteDataSource;

        @Inject
        public Repository(DataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory) {
            this.localDataSource = dataSourceFactory.createLocalDataSource();
            this.remoteDataSource = dataSourceFactory.createRemoteDataSource();
        }

        @Override
        public String getMovieName() {
            String name = localDataSource.getMovieName();
            return name.isEmpty() ? remoteDataSource.getMovieName() : name;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please add example code.

Comment: Ok i will add in two hours.